# CruiseControl.rb with RSpec: Rake task 'spec' not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cruisecontrol, cruisecontrol.rb

I'm trying to use CruiseControl.rb (ver. 2.0.0pre1) with RSpec for my Ruby on Rails 3 app. The `cruise_config.rb` for my project looks like this:

```
Project.configure do |project|
  project.rake_task = 'db:migrate db:test:prepare spec'
  project.scheduler.polling_interval = 1.hour
  project.scheduler.always_build = false
end
```

But when I try to run a build with CruiseControl, it says:

```
rake aborted!
Custom rake task(s) 'spec' not defined

Tasks: TOP => cc:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It can't find the spec rake task to run the RSpec tests. I also tried to define a custom rake task inside my `Rakefile` and removed the `project.rake_task = 'db:migrate db:test:prepare spec'` line inside the `cruise_config.rb`:

```
desc "Custom Task for CruiseControl.rb"
task :cruise do
  puts "Custom Rake task"
  Rake::Task['db:migrate'].execute
  Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].execute
  Rake::Task['spec'].execute
end
```

If i do so, CruiseControl says

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tasks: TOP => cruise
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[CruiseControl] Invoking Rake task "cruise"
Custom Rake task
```

Does anybody have CruiseControl.rb working with RSpec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you have the `:spec` task defined in your `Rakefile`, for RSpec 2, it looks like this:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
```

Comment: One more question, maybe you can help: When I run tests from cruisecontrol by specifying ``project.rake_task = 'spec'`` inside the ``cruise_config.rb`` cruisecontrol passes the build even when a test fails. I read sth about exti status, but nothing helped.

Comment: i'm not using cruise control, sorry